# SQL Query results different on different environments

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

There are 21 rows in the table. 7 are for year 2011, 7 are for 2012 and the remaining 7 are for 2013. I want to get the latest year's 7 rows.

```
SELECT S1, S2, S1 * S2 AS M 
FROM   BLGND
WHERE  DID = @dID AND 
       PMID = @pmID AND 
       yearr IN (SELECT MAX(yearr) AS y FROM BLGND AS BLGND_1)
```

I successfully bring the latest year's rows with the query above in MS Visual Studio Environment. But When I run the query in an ASP.NET page It brings all 21 records.

In other words `yearr IN (SELECT MAX(yearr) AS y FROM BLGND AS BLGND_1)` makes no difference.

`yearr` column's type is `int`

What could be the problem? OR is there a better query you know?

Comment: Why the IN clause when you know the year and you expect just one year to search for? By the way I think YEAR is a reserved word

Comment: What is `year` data type? Does using simply `[year] = (SELECT MAX([year]) FROM BLGND)` make any diff

Comment: You must have made some error when executing the query from ASP.NET, this should work (although you could use `=` instead of `IN` in the where). If the query is executed properly, the difference is probably related to ANSI settings regarding the query, ie. NULL handling etc., where the defaults might be different for VS and ASP.NET.

Comment: @Steve It is not year in my own query. I did it just to avoid localization. The field year is not year actually.

Comment: if I run `SELECT MAX([year]) AS y FROM BLGND AS BLGND_1` it gets 2013 in one row

Comment: You might want to run SQL Profiler against the DB then access it using the ASP.Net site to check exactly what query is being executed to the DB, and with what values.

Comment: You could just select TOP 7 and order by the year field.

Comment: I am so sorry. I was running query in a try -catch block. So after removing block I have seen the error. It was due to a parameter error. Query is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write

```
SELECT S1, S2, S1 * S2 AS M 
FROM   BLGND
WHERE  DID = @dID AND 
       PMID = @pmID AND 
       YEAR([fieldWithDate]) = @yearRequested
```

Where `fieldWithDate` is assumed to be a `smalldatetime` or `datetime` field from which you want to get the year value and @yearRequested is a parameter that you pass to your query from your code.
You could extract the year value using the [YEAR(expression)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx) T-SQL function

Of course, if the field to search for the year value is just an integer containing the year values of your rows the query is simpler

```
SELECT S1, S2, S1 * S2 AS M 
FROM   BLGND
WHERE  DID = @dID AND 
       PMID = @pmID AND 
       fieldWithYearValue = @yearRequested
```

If you don't want to pass the parameter for the year, but just want to retrieve always the set of rows of the last year for a specific user then

```
SELECT S1, S2, S1 * S2 AS M 
FROM   BLGND
WHERE  DID = @dID AND 
       PMID = @pmID AND 
       fieldWithYearValue = (SELECT MAX(fieldWithYearValue) FROM BLGND)
```

Comment: yearr column is an `int`.

Comment: Better then, no need to use the YEAR function, just a WHERE a = @param and param is the value 2013 or 2012 or 2011 or whatever year you search for

Comment: But each year some of the users could enter new records which I cannot control

Comment: I don't understand. If instead of 7 record there are 8 or 9 or 10 this query retrieve them as well (of course if DID AND PMID conditions are respected )

Comment: there are only 7 keys for users to fill and they can enter only 7 values. Neither less nor more.

Comment: I have already tried third query you proposed. Nothing changes.

Comment: Can't really explain that, unless there is something in your code that creates a different scenario or the database content is different, but, as is, this query should work. If you can, try it using Sql Server Management Studio on the target database, if not, then add some debugging or logging code to your asp.net app to check the code path that leads to the above query call.